# Rich Text Editor for JavaFX

Tags: javafx-2

is there any rich text editor plugin for JavaFx other than JavaFx HTML Editor?So I need Special character and insert image options.
These options are not in HTML Editor.Please any one can help me.

Answer (score 3):

This is now available as part of JavaFX 8 (TextFlow)
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html

```
 Text text1 = new Text("Big italic red text");
 text1.setFill(Color.RED);
 text1.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontPosture.ITALIC, 40));
 Text text2 = new Text(" little bold blue text");
 text2.setFill(Color.BLUE);
 text2.setFont(Font.font("Helvetica", FontWeight.BOLD, 10));
 TextFlow textFlow = new TextFlow(text1, text2);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plans for Java 8u40

https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/OpenJFX/8u40

Answer (score 0):

There is now available Rich Text Area from Gluon

https://github.com/gluonhq/rich-text-area